# Is there a Way To Define Table Name in the API Url

Tags: php, mysql, api

I am a noob to PHP and MySQL. I was searching for a way to access my tables in my Database and get the Data in them in Rows Format. I found the Following Code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","someuser","somepassword");

if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("TestDatabase", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer");

$output = array();
if ($result)
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $output[] = $row;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Now the problem is I have about more than 24 Tables in my database. So I was hoping Is there a way To Enter the Name Of the Table Through a Access URL like API. If there is then please help me. Thanks In Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very easy way to pass some request type id (table) via the url.

However without taking appropriate measures, this is calling for **big trouble**.

Imagine that you make the url to look like `https://myserver.com/myfile.php?table=aaa` and then change your query to `"select * from {$_GET['table']}"`. Then a malicious user may trick your code into selecting data from any database/table you have access to (by using `dbname.table`), including `mysql` system tables like `mysql.user`. From your original post its visible that you are using the `root` user to access the database, and most probably it has access to everything - generally its a good idea to create a separate database user that have access only to what is needed to do.

Another point is that you have to always verify/escape user input that makes it into `sql` queries (or use an API that can do variable binding), because in this way any malicious user may execute arbitrary code on your `sql` server. Check google for `sql injection` for more info.

As a simple solution I would recommend to use code like this to explicitly allow specific tables:

```
$allowedtables=array('aaa'=>1,'bbb'=>1);
if (!$allowedtables[$_GET['table']])
    return;
$query="select * from {$_GET['table']}";
```

A different, but not less important topic is that using deprecated API is not recommended for any new code...

Comment: Hi for tis i have created an API its url is like this:
http://mywebsite/api/folder/index.php

but whenever i try to access it it gives me an error. Can u help??

Answer (score 1):

PHP provides three different MySQL API extensions:

1. **MySQL Improved Extension**: This extension fully supports the authentication protocol used in MySQL 5.0, as well as the Prepared Statements and Multiple Statements APIs. In addition, this extension provides an advanced, object-oriented programming interface.
2. **MySQL Functions (PDO_MYSQL)**: It's a MySQL driver for the PHP database abstraction layer PDO (PHP Data Objects). The PDO MySQL driver sits in the layer below PDO itself, and provides MySQL-specific functionality. This extension is available as of PHP 5.1.0.
3. **Original MySQL API**: Available for PHP versions 4 and 5, this extension is intended for use with MySQL versions prior to MySQL 4.1. This extension does not support the improved authentication protocol used in MySQL 4.1, nor does it support prepared statements or multiple statements. To use this extension with MySQL 4.1, you will likely configure the MySQL server to set the old_passwords system variable to 1.

`Original MySQL API` was removed from PHP 5.5.0. If you are using the PHP version 5.5.0 or more the you have to migrate to either `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL`.

You can refer to the docs which are available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-introduction.html) for further reference.